# Pseudoinverse of a matrix with columns of exponential decays

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, pseudoinverse

I want to calculate the pseudoinverse $A^+$ of a matrix $A$ whose columns are exponential decays:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    e^{-\alpha_{0}t_{0}} & e^{-\alpha_{1}t_{0}} & e^{-\alpha_{2}t_{0}} \\
    e^{-\alpha_{0}t_{1}} & e^{-\alpha_{1}t_{1}} & e^{-\alpha_{2}t_{1}} \\
    e^{-\alpha_{0}t_{2}} & e^{-\alpha_{1}t_{2}} & e^{-\alpha_{2}t_{2}} \\
    \vdots & \vdots &\vdots \\
    e^{-\alpha_{0}t_{n}} & e^{-\alpha_{1}t_{n}} & e^{-\alpha_{2}t_{n}} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

where  $ t = 0,1,2,...n $.

$\alpha_{0}, \alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}$ are positive numbers. One of these alphas could be zero, meaning a column would be all ones.

Using exponential sum formulas I can calculate $A^TA$, but I wonder if there is a method to compute $A^+$ directly